# In ASP.NET MVC, move Authentication Models to a Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working on a new project in **ASP.NET MVC 5** with **Entity Framework 6 Code First**.

**CURRENT STATE**

I have two projects within one solution. One is the Front-End (MVC) and the other is a Class Library that I hope would house all my Model classes (Not ViewModels).

As we all know, when you start a new MVC project, the Identity Models sit within the [Models] folder. Since these logically belong in my Class Library project, I would like to move them there.

[image: solution explorer]

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Inside the [Authentication] folder I have gone ahead and created an `ApplicationUser.cs` class. Now by simply looking at `IdentityModels.cs` I know that I would need to reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` among other things.

So I right click on the Reference for the BB.DOMAIN project and click {Add Reference}. But I can't see the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` library anywhere!

[image: adding references]

**CLARIFICATION REQUIRED**

Am I doing the right thing here? My current thinking is that I am doing something one shouldn't typically do! But then everywhere you read, you get told that all your core entities should typically sit in one place.

Another thing I am confused about already but haven't got to is this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

When I get to add `ApplicationDbContext.cs` to my [Authentication] folder in BB.DOMAIN. In order to make everything sit in the same database, do I simply change `base("DefaultConnection")` to whatever the name of my connection string is in my other `DbContext` class which sits inside the [Context] folder?

I want all my entities driving this application to sit in one database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The super class `IdentityUser` which used in `IdentityModel` file came from [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/) package, not part of .Net Framework 4.5.

You need to add this nuget package and dependencies to the project `BB.DOMAIN`.

Comment: Thank you SilverFox. Thinking about it, do I need to add the `ApplicationDbContext` if I already have a `BBContext` of my own? Why would I need 2 contexts? Or is it a must for Authentication?

Comment: Well, `ApplicationDbContext` has been used by `ApplicationUserManager` to store user data. If you want to merge it into `BBContext`, make sure change all uses to `BBContext`.

Comment: thanks, or I can keep it and just tell it to use the same connection string as my other context right?

Comment: Yes, I prefer to keep `ApplicationDbContext` for user authentication, while `BBContext` for business logic. It makes every DbContext simple and focus on its own business.

Comment: I have one question for you: If I want to login, should I do the logic in the class library or keep it in the MVC application? I want to be able to get logged in user information in both projects, simple things like getUserId, IsAuthenticated, IsInRole. What should be done in mvc and what should be done on the class library? Perhaps you can elaborate your answer.